# Live app crash with EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uitextfield

I've a random crash on my live app which I can't reproduce. Following is the code. Since crash happens at line number 20, which is an outlet, it seems there is something wrong with my custom text field. I'm not able to figure out what is wrong. Any help?

**Crashlytics Log**

> Crashed: com.apple.main-thread EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS
>   0x00000002d37a1db0

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x1d6777530 objc_msgSend + 16
1  Foundation                     0x1d800a8d4 __NSThreadPerformPerform + 336
2  CoreFoundation                 0x1d75162bc __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
3  CoreFoundation                 0x1d751623c __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 88
4  CoreFoundation                 0x1d7515b24 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 176
5  CoreFoundation                 0x1d7510a60 __CFRunLoopRun + 1004
6  CoreFoundation                 0x1d7510354 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
7  GraphicsServices               0x1d971079c GSEventRunModal + 104
8  UIKitCore                      0x203ac7b68 UIApplicationMain + 212
9  myapp                          0x10040f454 main + 20 (ProfileViewController.swift:20)
10 libdyld.dylib                  0x1d6fd68e0 start + 4
```

**Code**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

    let menu = menuItems[indexPath.row]
    let menuTitle = menu.menuTitle

    switch menuTitle{

    case "My Profile":
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "myProfileSegue", sender: cell)
    //....
    }
}

class ProfileViewController: UIViewController {
    // ..
    @IBOutlet weak var emailTextField: CustomTextField! // Line no. 20
}

class CustomTextField: UITextField {

    var bottomBorder = UIView()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.initialize()

        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        bottomBorder = UIView.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0))
        bottomBorder.backgroundColor = .lightGreyColour
        bottomBorder.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        addSubview(bottomBorder)

        bottomBorder.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        bottomBorder.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor).isActive = true
        bottomBorder.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor).isActive = true
        bottomBorder.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 1).isActive = true
    }

    func initialize() {
        let clearButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 16, height: 16))
        clearButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "Glyph/16x16/Clear")!, for: .normal)

        self.rightView = clearButton
        clearButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(clearClicked), for: .touchUpInside)

        self.clearButtonMode = .never
        self.rightViewMode = .whileEditing
    }

    @objc func clearClicked(sender:UIButton) {
        self.text = ""
        self.bottomBorder.backgroundColor = .lightGreyColour
    }
}
```

Comment: I've been reading but still can't figure out. Is it possible that it's a crash in crashlytics?

Comment: How is your VC instantiated?

Comment: performSegue(withIdentifier: "myProfileSegue", sender: cell). I've updated my question to show how it is instantiated.